# How do I delete _notes in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6?

Tags: dreamweaver

This has been annoying me for years. Every solution I try. Even starting new sites - even pressing do not maintain notes, even pressing clean up notes.. no matter what I do.. Adobe Dreamweaver from CS4 to CS5 and now CS6 - always makes a folder in every folder called "_notes"

How do I get rid of this pile of crap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Adobe's help in [Enable and disable Design Notes for a site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7e98a.html#WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7e97a) :

> 1. Select Site > Manage Sites.
> 2. In the Manage Sites dialog box, select a site, then click Edit.
> 3. In the Site Setup dialog box, expand Advanced Settings and select the Design Notes category.
> 4. Deselect Maintain Design Notes to disable Design Notes
> 5. If you want to delete all local Design Notes files for your site, click Clean Up, and then click Yes. (If you want to delete remote
>      Design Notes files, you’ll need to delete them manually).
>
> **Note:** The Clean Up Design Notes command only deletes MNO (Design
>   Notes) files. It does not delete the _notes folder or the dwsync.xml
>   file inside the _notes folder. Dreamweaver uses the dwsync.xml file to
>   maintain information about site synchronization.

So although Notes can be disabled, it seems rather a bad idea to delete the _notes folder if you intend doing site synchronization.

You could also try and disable site synchronization
in the Remote Info category of the site definition dialog box.
For more detail see [Maintain Synchronization Information site definition preference](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/synchronize-works-dreamweaver-8.html#main_maintain_sync_info).

With both settings disabled, Dreamweaver might give up on the _notes folder.

Comment: Basically DW is buggy with this feature and always has been and I think the accepted answer is to ignore it and crack on. I enjoy using Dreamweaver for my coding environment.

Comment: Suggest also looking at at [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 1):

This is an important point that is not well understood.

The 'Maintain Synchronisation' setting only creates a '_notes' folder once, in the website root.

The more annoying aspect, is the 'Design Notes' setting, which seems to create a '_notes' folder in every directory where files are updated.

For me, a good compromise is to keep the 'Maintain Synchronisation' setting turned on, and turn off the 'Design Notes' setting.

I don't mind having one '_notes' folder in the root, considering the advantages of maintaining synchronisation for uploading files. It makes updating the remote server at the end of each day, a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clean it on mac or linux is:

```
find . -name "_notes" -type d -empty -delete
```

https://gist.github.com/vlados/23c828643ce6ac8b71ce18835b6198f9

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...